# jquery problem with simple code

Tags: jquery

why this code is not working

```
    var name = $("#name").val();    
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var web = $("#web").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();


    if(name.length < 5){
        $("#name").css("border-color","red");
    } elseif (email.length < 5) {
        $("#email").css("border-color","red");
    } elseif (web.length < 5) {
        $("#web").css("border-color","red");
    } elseif (comment.length < 10) {
        $("#comment").css("border-color","red");         
    }else{

alert('ok');

}
```

and each val for one like this `<input id="name" type="text"  size="24" />`

Comment: What are you expecting it to do, and how does the actual behaviour deviate from this?

Comment: What isn't working? The highlighting? The Alert box?

Comment: You have a syntax error : 'elseif' should be 'else if'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript your `elseif` needs to be `else if`, like this:

```
if(name.length < 5) {
    $("#name").css("border-color","red");
} else if (email.length < 5) {
    $("#email").css("border-color","red");
} else if (web.length < 5) {
    $("#web").css("border-color","red");
} else if (comment.length < 10) {
    $("#comment").css("border-color","red");         
} else {
    alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: oh my god but phpDesigner 7 write it elseif

Answer (score 1):

The question wasn't all too clear about what the actual problem was but I will mention that borders have more than just a color when defining the CSS--the shorthand is like this:

```
border: [size] [style] [color];
```

So if your elements didn't originally have a border thickness/style you might not actually see anything show up when you set the color to red.

Give this a shot:

```
$("#name").css("border", "2px solid red");
```